# Balanced and Unbalanced Forces Help

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, everyday-life, laws-of-physics

I am a newbie pondering in Physics concepts. I just had a question about Newtonian physics.

> The reason why "everyday" objects come to a rest is because there are unbalanced forces working against them.

The answer was ***true***! I didn't understand that because can't you have a balanced force against something and then things would slow down to a stop also right. We are not trying to *change* the **velocity** here right. We are **not** messing with the direction so I thought balanced force might suffice.

If anyone could intuitively explain it, I'd be glad! (Although I shouldn't be saying this on SE, thanks a lot!)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "everyday objects come to a rest" means, so i'll try to illustrate my interpretation of the statement. For example, when you throw a ball in the air, you can watch it ascend and some time later come down to the surface again, and then come to rest there eventually (at least in lots of situations it would). Now, as you watch the ball ascend and then fall back down, there must be some force acting on it pulling it downwards, because else Newton's axioms would tell us that it would continue moving upwards into the direction you have thrown it. So the reason the ball comes back down to earth is a net unbalanced force acting on it, accelerating it in direction of the surface. A $\textit{balanced}$ force means afaik that the net force is equal to $0$, such that the velocity (and therefore the direction of locomotion) remains unchanged.

Therefore, if you are witnessing some object change its direction or speed of movement, there must be some kind of acceleration happening, which according to Newton means that the net force on it is not equal to $0$, or in other terminology, there are unbalanced forces acting on it.